# What is the problem with creating a mail client without a java mail library?

Tags: java, smtp, sendmail, smtpclient

```
import javax.net.ssl.SSLServerSocketFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class MailServer{
    public static void MailSender() throws Exception{
        String Reply;
        String To = "???@naver.com";
        String From = "???@naver.com";
        String Data = "Hello this is computer networking";

        SSLSocketFactory sslsocketf = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
        System.out.println("Connect Start");
        SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket)sslsocketf.createSocket("smtp.naver.com", 465);
        //Socket socket = new Socket("smtp.gmail.com", 465);
        System.out.println("Connect Success");


        BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

        PrintWriter outToServer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

        //String[] supported = socket.getSupportedCipherSuites();
        //socket.setEnabledCipherSuites(supported);

        Reply = inFromServer.readLine();
        if(Reply.startsWith("220"))
            System.out.println("Server Connect Success!");
        else {
            System.out.println("Server Connect Fail");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        System.out.println(Reply);
        //HELO command
        outToServer.println("HELO naver.com");
        Reply = inFromServer.readLine();
        ReplyCheck(Reply, "250");

        //MAIL FROM command
        outToServer.println("MAIL FROM: <" + From + ">");
        Reply = inFromServer.readLine();
        ReplyCheck(Reply, "250");

        //RCPT TO command
        outToServer.println("RCPT TO: <" + To + ">");
        Reply = inFromServer.readLine();
        ReplyCheck(Reply, "250");

        //DATA command
        outToServer.println("DATA");
        Reply = inFromServer.readLine();
        ReplyCheck(Reply, "354");
        outToServer.println(Data);
        outToServer.println(".");
        ReplyCheck(Reply, "250");

        //QUIT command
        outToServer.println("QUIT");
        Reply = inFromServer.readLine();
        ReplyCheck(Reply, "221");


        outToServer.close();
        inFromServer.close();
        socket.close();
    }

    public static void ReplyCheck(String Reply, String Status) throws Exception{
        System.out.println(Reply);
        if(!Reply.startsWith(Status))
            throw new Exception(Reply);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        try{
                MailServer.MailSender();
                System.out.println("Send Mail Success!");
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("Send Mail Fail");
                System.out.println(e.toString());
            }
    }
}
```

If you execute it, this phrase will appear and end

Connect Start
Connect Success
Server Connect Success!
220 smtp.naver.com ESMTP
250 smtp.naver.com Pleased to meet you
530 5.5.1 Authentication Required
Send Mail Fail
java.lang.Exception: 530 5.5.1 Authentication Required

I think it's a security problem(TLS/SSL), is there a solution?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a TLS problem. SMTP for submission (which is different from SMTP for relay) requires user authentication. Make sure you send `EHLO` instead of `HELO` (since `AUTH` is an extension of the Extended Simple Mail Transfer Protocol (ESMTP)). Right after, send `AUTH PLAIN value`, where `value` is what you get when you run `echo -ne '\0000username\0000password' | openssl base64` with your username and password for the outgoing mail server.